# Receiving null statements when parsing data from google maps api for Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, parsing

I am receiving null statements when parsing an Xml from a URL that is from Google maps api. I have no idea where I am doing something wrong.  I think it has to do with my elements and attributes but am not sure.  Can someone please point me in the right direction or point out my error?

Here are my three classes being used:

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class HandlingXML extends DefaultHandler {

    XMLDataCollected info = new XMLDataCollected();

    public String getInformation(){
        return info.dataToString();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (localName.equals("text")){
            String time = attributes.getValue("duration");
            info.setTime(time);
        }else if (localName.equals("text")){
            String distance = attributes.getValue("distance");
            info.setDistance(distance);
        }
    }

}


public class XMLDataCollected {
    String distance = null;
    String time = null;

    public void setTime(String t){
        time = t;
    }

    public void setDistance(String d){
        distance = d;
    }

    public String dataToString(){
        return "Total Distance: " + distance + ", Total Duration: " + time;
    }
}



import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MapParsing extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    static final String baseURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=";
    TextView tv;
    EditText origin, destination;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.destination_next_button);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_distance);
        origin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.startinglocation);
        destination = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.endinglocation);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String start = origin.getText().toString();
        String end = destination.getText().toString();

        StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
        URL.append(start + "&destinations=" + end + "&sensor=false");
        String fullUrl = URL.toString();
        try{
            URL website = new URL(fullUrl);
            //getting xmlreader to parse data
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            HandlingXML doWork = new HandlingXML();
            xr.setContentHandler(doWork);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
            String information = doWork.getInformation();
            tv.setText(information);
        }catch(Exception e){
            tv.setText("Error!");
        }
    }



    }
```

Here is my Activity_Main_xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gc"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/startinglocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/starting_location" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/endinglocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startinglocation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startinglocation"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/ending_location" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/destination_next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
        android:text="@string/next" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Vehicle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/endinglocation"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:entries="@array/Vehicles" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Vehicle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Vehicle"
        android:text="Vehicle Type:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Vehicle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Vehicle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/destination_next_button"
        android:text="TIme and Distance" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The XML I am trying to parse looks as follows:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status><origin_address>Indianapolis, IN, USA</origin_address>           <destination_address>Denver, CO, USA</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>55705</value>
<text>15 hours 28 mins</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>1742628</value>
<text>1,743 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Here is the link I am trying to pull from.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Indianapolis&destinations=Denver&sensor=false

Comment: Also should be a line in the XML file under origin_address :

Comment: <destination_address>Denver,CO,USA</destination_address

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this Example it works for Parsing the XML:

```
public class DOMParserDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//Get the DOM Builder Factory
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

//Get the DOM Builder
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

//Load and Parse the XML document
//document contains the complete XML as a Tree.
Document document = 
  builder.parse(
    ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("xml/employee.xml"));

List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

//Iterating through the nodes and extracting the data.
NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

  //We have encountered an <employee> tag.
  Node node = nodeList.item(i);
  if (node instanceof Element) {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.id = node.getAttributes().
        getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();

    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
      Node cNode = childNodes.item(j);

      //Identifying the child tag of employee encountered. 
      if (cNode instanceof Element) {
        String content = cNode.getLastChild().
            getTextContent().trim();
        switch (cNode.getNodeName()) {
          case "firstName":
            emp.firstName = content;
            break;
          case "lastName":
            emp.lastName = content;
            break;
          case "location":
            emp.location = content;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    empList.add(emp);
  }

}

//Printing the Employee list populated.
for (Employee emp : empList) {
  System.out.println(emp);
}

  }
 }

class Employee{
String id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String location;

@Override
public String toString() {
 return firstName+" "+lastName+"("+id+")"+location;
}
}
```

Please see example XML file:

```
<employees>
<employee id="111">
<firstName>Rakesh</firstName>
<lastName>Mishra</lastName>
<location>Bangalore</location>
</employee>
<employee id="112">
<firstName>John</firstName>
<lastName>Davis</lastName>
<location>Chennai</location>
</employee>
<employee id="113">
<firstName>Rajesh</firstName>
<lastName>Sharma</lastName>
<location>Pune</location>
</employee>
</employees>
```

It seems that there might be some problem at the parsing side ... use it if it helps !!

Comment: Will SAX parser not work in this case at all? I understand what you are saying but this XML has no "id" or element it just has attributes does it not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Sax Parser :

```
public void ReadAndWriteXMLFileUsingSAXParser(){

    try
    {
        DefaultHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        InputStream rStream = null;
        rStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("location.xml");
        saxParser.parse(rStream, handler);
    }catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Handler class :

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
String rootname;Attributes atr;
private boolean flag=false;private Vector data;
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                         String qName, Attributes atts)  {
 rootname=localName;
 atr=atts;

 if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("address_component")){
     data=new Vector();
     flag=true;
 }


}
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
    String value=new String(ch,start,length);
    if(flag)
    {
        if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("type")){
            data.addElement(value) ;
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++"+value);
        }
        if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("long_name")){
            data.addElement(value) ;
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++"+value);
        }
        if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("short_name")){
            data.addElement(value) ;
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++"+value);
        }
    }

}
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName){
    rootname=localName;
     if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("address_component")){
         flag=false;
     }
}
}
```

My Xml would be like this:

```
<address_component>
<long_name>Gujarat</long_name>
<short_name>Gujarat</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
```

Comment: My output is coming up blank now instead of null.  Is this because I am pulling int types and not strings since the text elements are 15 hours 28 mins and 1,743 km? Or would this matter?

Comment: @user3496650  - Okay, look in my answer you have one element of address_component, and you access values in that.. In your case you can make different calls for Duration and Distance. so address_component = (Duration / Distance) and where you were getting type just get text and value

Comment: I do that but then don't know how to call the information.

Comment: public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
  String value = new String(ch, start, length);
  if (flag) {
   if (rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
    data.addElement(value);
    info.setDistance(value);                this gives me the blank statement... sorry I am new at this :/

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you New and if XML output is not compulsory than call Google API and get JSON o/p from this API:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Indianapolis&destinations=Denver&sensor=false

And than you can parse it like:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseText);
    // routesArray contains ALL routes
    JSONArray rows = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");       
    JSONArray elements = route.getJSONArray("elements");
    JSONObject leg = elements.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject durationObject = leg.getJSONObject("duration");
    String duration = durationObject.getString("text");
```

Try to use JSON it is more faster and easy to parse and better to Use.

Comment: Where are you getting the route variable? I tried creating a local variable but keep receiving an error.